# IdentityServer3 with EF support and Asp.NEt Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am planning to use IdentityServer3 with [IdentityServer3.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework/) for Clients,Scopes and OperationalData. And I also want to configure user store using [IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity/)

What is the recommendation here? Is it okay to have single database for clients, scopes, operational data and Asp.Net Identity? Will there be an issue with [EF migration](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ef/migrations.html) if we have ASP.NET identity tables in the same database?

Or should I create seprate database one for IdentityServer3.EntityFramework and another for ASP.NET Identity?

I also want to configure users per client, I am not sure this is supported with IdentityServer3

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is any issue with combining the database but I did get two databases working.  in my case I am not using migrations and I am using a modified ef datastore for my users info. I do not recall the exact details but I did have to mess with some of the configuration to get it working.
right now I see the scopes and clients working for me, for roles I created my own authorize attribute to solve the "what kind of token has roles" thing that I never really understood all the way.  My experience has been one of trail and error as it seems like there is no one simple path in making OAuth / OIDC  work. Not the fault of Identity Server, it's due for the most part to the Oauth and OIDC specs.